# Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to implement a barcode finder in excel, so I have item names and barcodes in separate sheets depending on what group an item belongs to. The user clicks on a radio button (selecting Group 1, Group 2, or whatever) and a list box's fill range is set to one of the **dynamic name ranges I have defined**.

[image]

The user then click on a button in order to copy the barcode for the corrseponding item. Here is the macro associated with the button:

```
Sub Get_Barcode()
    Dim objData As New DataObject
    Dim barcode As String
    On Error GoTo Errorcatch
    barcode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ListBox1.Text, ListBox1.ListFillRange, 1, False)
    objData.SetText barcode
    objData.PutInClipboard
    MsgBox "Barcode " & barcode & " copied to clipboard"
Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

The problem is that it displays a `Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class` and I don't know what I am doing wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Changed corresponding line in original code with following:

> barcode=Application.VLookup(ListBox1.Text,ActiveWorkbook.Names(ListBox1.ListFillRange).RefersToRange, 2, False)